# Is the concurrent.futures ThreadPoolExecutor thread safe

Tags: python, concurrency

I want to know if the ThreadPoolExecutor in Python thread safe. I mean I want to instantiate a thread pool. I want to know if I access this thread pool from multiple threads to submit jobs, will it have any concurrency issues?